# How does fsync treat directory links?

Tags: linux, directory, system-calls

What is the meaning of the following statement from the [fsync man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html)

> Calling fsync() does not necessarily ensure that the entry in the
> directory containing the file has also reached disk.  For that an
> explicit fsync() on a file descriptor for the directory is also
> needed.

Does it mean that fsync won't update the directory metadata when I call fsync on a file?

Another quote for the same problem is (from Robert Love's Book of Linux System Programming):

> Neither function guarantees that any updated directory entries
> containing the file are synchronized to disk. This implies that if a
> file’s link has recently been updated, the file’s data may
> successfully reach the disk but not the associated directory entry,
> rendering the file unreachable.

Why would a file's data need to reach a directory link ? Correct me if I am wrong but the directories only contain the filename and the inode number for that file. The actual data is in the file. What is the meaning of "the data will reach the file but not the directory link" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means:

> if a file’s link has recently been updated
>
> the file’s data may successfully reach the disk but

*the associated directory entry might not successfully reach the disk*

> rendering the file unreachable.

This could be a concern when creating a new file.

I would ignore the generalization to "a file's link", unless you know hard links are being created.

> Does it mean that fsync won't update the directory metadata when I call fsync on a file?

Yes.  Or rather, you can't rely on it.  (It's possible some implementations would always update it before fsync returns.)

Comment: what metadata does the directory other than the name of the file and the inode number? Also does this question of not relying on `fync` only applicable when creating a file?

Comment: @ng.newbie it could apply e.g. if you created a second hard-link to a file, and then removed the first hard link.  The significant, required metadata is the file name and the inode.  I suspect there's nothing mutable in there (apart from the name), because of the possibility of multiple hardlinks.  However I believe some filesystems cache more information in there.  Specifically, whether the directory entry refers to a directory or a regular file etc.  See `getdents()`.  This might allow more efficient implementation of `find`, for example.

Comment: Wouldn’t ‘rename’ and ‘unlink’ system calls (in addition to ‘creat’) also update the files’ link, and so also require a call to ‘fsync’ on the containing directories?

Comment: @DonSlowik Yes, that's right.